# MySQL for Excel Add-In, failing to append

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I am using the MySQL for Excel add-in. I have been using this for months to highlight a set of data and load it into my database.

I added a new table last week, and was successfully loading data into it using the same method. It stopped working. When I attempt to Append data, I get an error dialogue box that says "Cannot Find Column 30"...which happens to be the number (and therefore) last column in my table.

Some more information:
- If I highlight this same set of data and try to write it to another table, it will allow me to (even though I don't confirm and do it). I get past the error dialogue box to the Mapping dialogue box. 
- I tried writing data from the previous table to this new problem table. I got the same error dialogue box.
This tells me that the problem is not with the data set. It is with the table.

I then deleted the table, all the connections and redid it from scratch. Still the same problem.

Where is this failing? Thank you.

Comment: is it possible to attach the Excel file, just removing sensitive data? the question is a bit confusing on it's own.

Answer (score 9):

ya even i had the same problem, even i tried the same way u did, like deleted the table recreated everything, it did not work, finally i tried to append some random table and went to "Advanced Options" at the bottom of the append pop up
in this u will see some "Stored Column mappings" and some mappings in it, now delete all of them and hit "Accept" now u can append the table

it will work

Comment: StackOverflow is not like your average help forum in that we don't encourage stories. We like answers brief and to-the-point.  We also appreciate correct grammar and word spelled out in full.

Comment: Great suggestion! It works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is super old but I have a solution because it just happened to me.

Try append on different table. When box pops up click 'Advanced Options'
Then under column mapping uncheck both:
(Automatically store the column mapping for the given table) AND
(Reload stored column mapping for the select table automatically)

Then goto the Stored mappings tab and delete all the stored mappings
Click Accept and then rejoice you are free of that error for life.
best -J

Comment: I know this answer is two years old, but thank you, this was the answer for me!

Answer (score 1):

If Excel does not show you the "Stored Column mappings" then connect to a MySQL table not used before in Excel, then retry the Append, the mapping will be shown. Then you can follow the answer provided by user3611272.

Answer (score 1):

Problem will be resolved by doing below steps:

1. Select any table from Table other than your target table.
2. Click on Append Data
3. Press "Advanced Options"
4. Select tab "Stored Mappings"
5. Delete your target table mapping and Accept.

it will solve the issue.